# Why does a clustered index prevent a deadlock?

Tags: sql, azure

I have frequent deadlocks occur on tables in Azure SQL that do not have any primary keys (or clustered indexes). The tables are populated by stored procedures that check for existence and then update or else they insert. The pseudocode for these stored procedures is below.

I have noticed that when I add a clustered index on all of the columns in the where conditions, I do not get deadlocks and these stored procedures can run concurrently on the same tables. When I add a non-clustered index or no index then I see these deadlocks and a "Table Scan" for the query plan. When the clustered indexes are there, it changes to a clustered index seek instead.

I believe that the reason I am not experiencing locks with clustered indexes is because the query plans end up using clustered index seeks instead of table scans. I believe that table scans cause larger locks than just the row affected but I cannot find information that supports it clearly in those terms. Am I on the right track? How do explain this behavior and what tools can I use to demonstrate why clustered indexes prevent deadlocks in my case?

```
BEGIN TRAN
IF EXISTS (select * from Table1 where unique columns = incoming parameters) with (nolock)
    UPDATE Table1
        set col1 = @col1
        set col2 = @col2
        set col3 = @col3
        ...
        set timestamp = @timestamp
    WHERE unique columns = @unique columns and timestamp > @timestamp

ELSE
    INSERT INTO Table1
        Col1,
        Col2,
        Col3,
        ...,
        Timestamp
    VALUES
        @Col1,
        @Col2,
        @Col3,
        ...,
        @Timestamp
COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: Here's an interesting article by Aaron Bertrand on doing Upserts, and locking: https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern  maybe give that a try and see if things change

Comment: Without a clustered index you end up with a heap table. These have interesting differences from tables with clustered indexes, but the bottom line is that they're almost never desirable for anything that's not a trivial, append-only table (and even then it's dubious). The locking strategies used for heap table inserts are different from those with clustered indexes, so your basic summary is not incorrect (even if the actual story is a little more involved). Even with clustered indexes deadlocks are possible, though, they're just less likely if the inserts themselves are faster.

Answer (score 1):

A clustered index **is** the actual table, it converts a table from a heap to an index, and all columns are included. A Non-Clustered Index can also have some columns included in the leaf (`INCLUDE (col3,col4)`), you appear not to have done so.

The type of deadlock you are experiencing is called a "key-lookup" deadlock. Usually it runs on these lines:

`UPDATE` statement uses the clustered index to find a row, takes out an exclusive lock (X-lock) on the row preventing readers and writers. It updates the CI, then goes to the NCI to update it, and X-locks that also.

At the same time, a `SELECT` statement scans or seeks an NCI and locks the row against writers (S-lock), this does not block the update as that is still doing the CI update, then does a key lookup to the CI for the remaining columns. The CI is locked against readers and writers, hence the deadlock.

The same would apply in the particular case you mention, which is where there is an NCI and no CI, just a heap. This manifests as an RID lookup instead of a Key Lookup in query plans.

To prevent this, either force the `SELECT` to use the CI, this is often inefficient. Or better, create an NCI that includes all columns needed in the query. Note: you can make them part of the `INCLUDE`, they don't need to be in the key of the index.

Comment: After further research it is actually an RID lock and not a key lock, since my tables have no keys or clustered indexes so far. Could it be that they are heaps and are acquiring a lock on the entire heap (entire resource)?

Comment: RID lock means a row lock on a heap. An Object lock will lock the whole table

Comment: so can that mean that the whole table is a heap?

Comment: Yes the table is either a heap or a clustered index, not both